# How to get csv.writer to remove the delimiter character inside of columns?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to convert a `json` table to a csv file but the problem is that when a field contains the delimiter character it gets copied just the same and it can cause some interpretation problems later on. Is there an option in `csv.writer` to remove delimiter characters inside the fields if they are present ? Or at least brace the field with quotes I guess.

Comment: maybe something like `data.replace(",", "")` ?

Comment: Why removing delimiters, depriving you of possibly valuable information? Moreover, delimiters should be quoted automatically, this case is of course handled by the `csv` module, you shoudn't have any problem. Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre because when you try to read it with let's say R it causes bugs because some rows are detected to have more columns that others. Also you are right csv.writer seem to quotes fields containing a delimiter automatically, however this seem to work only for the default delimiter ",", if you change it to ";" it no longer quotes fields containing ";"

Comment: @ChiseledAbs: That would sound like a bug in the csv module, but I couldn't reproduce the behaviour that you described; If I create a `csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')`, the resulting object escapes the new delimiter automatically for me. As Jean already asked, could you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the Python code that causes the csv module to not escape the delimiter properly? If it indeed fails to escape the delimiter under some circumstances, it should probably be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing

```
quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL
```

to the `csv.writer` constructor. That will force the library to quote all fields.

Here is a link to the documentation for the [`quoting`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting) parameter and the link to the documentation for [`csv.QUOTE_ALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL).